# Java scheduling service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks

I'm needing to make a service that schedules jobs that are basically get requests that hit some servlet. I tried to do this w/ a servlet context listener based on this post, [Running a background Java program in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907502/running-a-background-java-program-in-tomcat), but the web.xml changes that were defined are causing 404 errors on the Tomcat server. Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

One idea I have at this point is to define a runnable servlet

```
public class Service extends HttpServlet implements Runnable    {
     //Does stuff
     init()  {
         new Thread(this);
     }
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can look into using quartz scheduler for jobs :

```
http://quartz-scheduler.org/
```

for instance (not specific to your task):

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class SchedulerJob implements Job
{
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
  throws JobExecutionException {

    Map dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    SchedulerTask task = (SchedulerTask)dataMap.get("schedulerTask");
    task.printSchedulerMessage();
  }
}
```

Another option (for a quick turaround) would be to just use a cron job or windows task manager depending on your OS.