# Regarding Java Executor framework in a Web applications enviornment

Tags: java, executorservice

I planned to use executor framework in one of my web application for background process such as sending mail and logging the details.When i start reading about the Executor API , i understood that it  offers thread pooling facility. But i have a thought like we no need  thread pooling mechanism in web applications. Because by default my application server controlling the thread polling and all right. So my point here is we no need to implement thread pooling in web application scenarios? Is this point is right or wrong?

Comment: It is right, you should not use thread-pooling or any additional threading in web-applications under normal circumstances. This is managed well by the servlet-container. More specific answers require more specific questions here.

Comment: Since Java EE 7 there is now a 'ManagedExecutorService' , which is the EE analogue to the SE ExecutorService. It is designed to be used in 'managed environments', i.e, by applications running in an EE server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends which threads you are referring to.

The threads used to handle requests coming into the application server are handled by the container itself. You don't need to worry about that.

However, if your application needs to handle longer tasks that are initiated by requests, and you want to respond to the requests quickly, then you can have threads handle these tasks. To do this, you can start a number of threads at the [application startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and use them when you need to run a long task. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907502/running-a-background-java-program-in-tomcat).

Comment: In any case the parent thread(ie started by the application server)  will run until the child thread(started my application using executor) finish right or not?

Comment: The main thread, yes. Not the one handling the request. That one will run in parallel and finish processing the request while the task is running.

Comment: Tip: Be sure to shutdown your executor in the web app’s `ServletContextListener::contextDestroyed` method or else the executor’s threads will survive past the shutdown of your web app. Then you have zombie threads, never-ending but without a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java EE 7 there is now a 'ManagedExecutorService' , which is the EE analogue to the SE ExecutorService. It is designed to be used in 'managed environments', i.e, by applications running in an EE server. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html

Answer (score 1):

The server containers provide runtime support for **Java EE application** components

> (such as servlets and Enterprise JavaBeansTM (EJBTM))

. They provide a layer between application component code and platform services and resources. All application component code is run on a thread managed by a container and each container typically expects all access to container-supplied objects to occur on the same thread.

It is because of this behavior that application components are typically unable to reliably use other **Java EE platform services** from a thread that is not managed by the container. **Java EE Product Providers** also discourage the use of resources in a non-managed way, because it can potentially undermine the enterprise features that the platform is designed to provide such as

> availability, security, and reliability and scalability.

Check this [link](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236)

Answer (score -2):

That is incorrect. Application server does manage its own thread pool, but the threads created by the executor framework are not managed by application server.