# Executors.newFixedThreadPool hanged threads

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

As it said in javadoc

> The threads in the pool will exist
>         until it is explicitly shutdowned by `ExecutorService#shutdown()`

If I have a web application on Tomcat. On startup It creates a fixed thread pool. Also I have investigated

```
      public  static void main(String ... strings)  {
            ExecutorService s = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            s.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        System.out.println("zzz");
                }
            });
      }
```

that threads in the above example don't exist until I submit them  to ExecutorService. When `main` method ends I see a `javaw.exe` in the list of processes of the task manger(win 7 os). So I assume that instance of the jvm that run that example still exists. When I add `s.shutdown()` - there are no any java process in the process list.

**Question 1**: when the tomcat suddenly stops due to some errors, will the java process hang in the memory(if previously some tasks were submitted  to thread pool mentioned above);

**Question 2**: if the answer to previouse question is yes, are there some ways to make threads in pool to be deamon or maybe are there some ways to handle such tomcat/myapp stops to invoke `ExecutorService#shutdown()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Question 1: when the tomcat suddenly stops due to some errors, will the java process hang in the memory(if previously some tasks were submitted to thread pool mentioned above);

If it doesn't shutdown the `ExecutorService` then yes, it will hang.

> Question 2: if the answer to previouse question is yes, are there some ways to make threads in pool to be deamon...

Yes there is.  You can provide a thread factory.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = newFixedThreadPool(numThreads,
    new ThreadFactory() {
        public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
            Thread thread = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    });
```

As @matt b mentioned, another mechanism to ensure that the thread-pool is shutdown is to [define a shutdown hook/listener in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549924/shutdown-hook-for-java-web-application).

Comment: Note that if you're using guava (and if you aren't, why not?) such a ThreadFactory is available from MoreExecutors.daemonThreadFactory().

Comment: also note that if you are creating an Executor or ThreadPool in your webapp, it's best to setup a ContextListener to shutdown the executor/pool so you can give your tasks a chance to shutdown cleanly rather than being abruptly terminated in the middle of their work.

Comment: Good point @matt.  I've added a link to some info about that.

Comment: I have heard recently that application servers  kill all such threads(if they exist) on shutdown, is it true?

Comment: Not that I know of @maks but hopefully other folks who have direct experience chime in.