# Initializing Synchronous ThreadPool Executor at startup of server

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, synchronized

I want to initialize Synchronized static singleton ThreadPool Executor with my defined properties.

I want it to available through out the application and should be destroyed when server is restarted or stopped.

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutor extends java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private static Properties properties;
    static {
        try {
            properties.load(ThreadPoolExecutor .class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static final int defaultCorePoolSize = Integer.valueOf((String) properties.get("CORE_POOL_SIZE"));
    static final int defaultMaximumPoolSize = Integer.valueOf((String) properties.get("MAX_POOL_SIZE"));
    static final long defaultKeepAliveTime = Integer.valueOf((String) properties.get("KEEP_ALIVE_TIME"));
    static final TimeUnit defaultTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
    static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    private static ThreadPoolExecutor instance;

    private ThreadPoolExecutor() {
        super(defaultCorePoolSize, defaultMaximumPoolSize, defaultKeepAliveTime, defaultTimeUnit, workQueue);
    }

    synchronized static ThreadPoolExecutor getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ThreadPoolExecutor();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

This is what I have done till now (I am newbie to Multi-threading).

As my application is completely based on Multi-threading, how do I achieve my requirements and anything to improve here!
As I said, how do i maintain/make it available through out the application.

Comment: What is your server? Does it have startup and shutdown hooks?

Comment: Tomcat 7 and it will be deployed in Jboss 7 too

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549924/130224

Comment: I am aware of that and Implemented in the similar way. I would like to see if any flaw is there in my threadpool as application depends more on multi-threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class that implements [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in your `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <!-- ... -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.domain.ThreadPoolManager</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

The class `ThreadPoolManager` should override the methods [`contextInitilized(ServletContextEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) and [`contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29). The method [`contextInitilized(ServletContextEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) gets invoked the web application initialization process is starting. So, you should do your initialization work there. Similarly, the method [`contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) gets invoked when the servlet context is about to be shut down. So, you should do your clean up work there.

Comment: I have done the samething

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
private static ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = ThreadPoolExecutor.getInstance();

//SOME CODE 
}

is this fine?

Comment: You should do the initialization and cleanup work in the methods that override methods of the interface. See my updated answer for more details.