# Shutdown Thread Pool when application stops or server shutsdown

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat7, threadpool

I have a thread-pool in my application which I want to shutdown only when application stops. I tried 3 ways:

1.Shutting down in context destroyed:

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("CALLING CONTEXT DESTROYED.");
    PersistSigningExecutor.getService().shutdown();
}
```

2.Shutting down in destroy method of any servlet:

```
@Override
public void destroy() {   
    super.destroy();
    System.out.println("SHUTTING DOWN THREAD-POOLS");  
    PersistSigningExecutor.getService().shutdown();
}
```

3.Adding shutdown hook in contextInitialised

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {       
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("SHUTTING DOWN THREAD-POOLS");                        
                    PersistSigningExecutor.getService().shutdown();

            }
        });

}
```

But none of them are working. I am not seeing any print statements. And also at the end I am getting log saying :

```
SEVERE: The web application [/app] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

which means the thread is still not shutdown. How to shutdown this thread-pool properly when server is shutdown or application is undeployed?

Comment: Thread pool = `ExecutorService`?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549924/shutdown-hook-for-java-web-application

Answer (score 0):

make the thread demon (`setDamon(boolean)`), so that it will stop when jvm starts shutting down basically demon thread does not prevent JVM to shutdown.

Or else if you plan to use `ExecutorService` then you need to call `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This fails if the OP needs the threads to end currently running tasks.  `daemon` threads stop in the same way a `Thread.stop` does.  So if there is any needed coordination to 'shutdown' this will fail.